# Is there OS X JavaScript editor with "click to go to definition" feature?

Tags: javascript, macos, editor

Similar questions have been asked many times before i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724234/preferred-javascript-editor-for-mac or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support

At work I'm using Visual Studio with JetBrains ReSharper and clicking on function name to jump to definition is a killer feature for me.

Looking for something similar on Mac OS X. Normally I'm trying to use Sublime Text and Coda - maybe you know how to enable **"click on function name = jump to definition"**? I just find myself clicking CTRL + function name and nothing happens.

Thanks is advance for any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains WebStorm:

> Go to declaration — navigates to where the function, variable or label
>   in question is declared with a simple hotkey or ⌘Click.

[image]

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/